# How to store an object in Riak with the Java client?

Tags: java, riak, key-value-store

I have setup Riak on a Ubuntu machine, and it seam to work if I do `riak ping`.

Now I would like to use the [Riak Java client](http://bitbucket.org/jonjlee/riak-java-client/wiki/Home) to store an object, but it doesn't work. I get `com.basho.riak.client.response.RiakIORuntimeException` when I try to store an object. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to test if I can access riak from my java client? Do I have to create a Bucket first? how?

```
import com.basho.riak.client.RiakClient;
import com.basho.riak.client.RiakObject;
import com.basho.riak.client.response.FetchResponse;

public class RiakTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // connect
        RiakClient riak = new RiakClient("http://192.168.1.107:8098/riak");

        // create object
        RiakObject o = new RiakObject("mybucket", "mykey", "myvalue");

        // store
        riak.store(o);  
    }
}
```

Comment: It seam to be problem with my network access: http://superuser.com/questions/132865/can-not-connect-to-service-with-my-public-ip-only-with-localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jonas, by default Riak's HTTP server binds only to the local interface (127.0.0.1).  To change this, shutdown your instance and edit the app.config file.  Change the setting "riak_web_ip" to "0.0.0.0", which will bind to all interfaces.

For more information, see http://wiki.basho.com/display/RIAK

Answer (score 0):

The last up to date [wiki page](http://wiki.basho.com/Adding-and-Removing-Nodes.html).

So you need:

1. Shutdown your nodes
2. Remove directory "ring" in each node: {node directory}/data/ring
3. In etc/vm.args change name from riak@127.0.0.1 to smth like riak@192.168.1.10
4. In etc/app.config change http and pb_ip settings

   ```
   from http, [ {"127.0.0.1", 8098 } ]},  to http, [ {"0.0.0.0", 8098 } ]},
   ```

   and

   ```
   from {pb_ip,   "127.0.0.1" }, to {pb_ip,   "0.0.0.0" },
   ```